# Number of $k$-parts in the set of all compositions of integer $n$.

Tags: combinatorics

This seems like a basic question but I've been searching for the answer for a long time (days).

Define $p^n_k$ as the number of $k$-parts in the set of all compositions of integer $n$.

For example for $n=3$, we have the compositions:

[
(3), (2, 1), (1, 2), (1, 1, 1)
]

There are five $1$s, two $2$s and one $3$, so $p^3_1 = 5$, $p^3_2 = 2$, and $P^3_3 = 1$.

Is there a general expression for $p^n_k$?.

Note that this is different from the commonly asked question about the number of compositions of length $k$ for the integer $n$, for which the answer is ${n-1}\choose{k-1}$.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Just to clarify, is $p_{2}^{3}=2$ because there are two partitions with length $2$ or because the number $2$ shows up twice?

Comment: It's because the number $2$ shows up twice. Thanks!

Comment: Just edited for more clarity :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways the number $k$ can show up in a partition:

1. $(k,x_{1},…,x_{r})$ $|$ $x_{1}+…+x_{r}=n-k$. There are $2^{n-k-1}$ partitions of $n-k$
2. $(x_{1},…,x_{r},k)$ $|$ $x_{1}+…+x_{r}=n-k$. There are $2^{n-k-1}$ partitions of $n-k$
3. $(x_{1},…,x_{r},k,y_{1},…,y_{s})$ $|$ $(x_{1}+…+x_{r}=a)$, $(y_{1}+…+y_{s}=b)$, $(a+b=n-k)$. There are $2^{a-1}\cdot 2^{b-1}=2^{n-k-2}$ possibilities for each $a$ and $b$ and there are $\binom{n-k-1}{1}$ possible pairs $(a,b))$

Therefore the desired expression is given below:

$$
\begin{align}
p_{k}^{n}&=2^{n-k-1}+2^{n-k-1}+\binom{n-k-1}{1}\cdot 2^{n-k-2}\\
\\
&=2^{n-k}+\binom{n-k-1}{1}\cdot 2^{n-k-2}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! Well done. This is very helpful.

Comment: I notice that the answer can be simplified to $p^n_k = (n-k+3) 2^{n - k - 2}$ because ${{n}\choose{1}} = n$.

Comment: @b_plastic actually you shouldn’t. $\binom{n}{1}=n$ if and only if $n\geq 0$. In our case try $p_{3}^{3}$

Comment: @b_plastic i mean the way i derived the expression, i assumed $n-k-1\geq 0$ and I will omit the second term otherwise

Comment: Good point - I figured you wouldn't have missed that.